# Create our own control for jquery time picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I need to create textbox for hour and minute selection of jquery UI. Here is my code:

```
 var myControl1 = {
    create: function (tp_inst, obj, unit, val, min, max, step) {
        $('<input class="ui-timepicker-input" placeholder="HH" value="' + val + '" style="width:50%">')
            .appendTo(obj)
            .text({                   
                change: function (e, ui) { // key events
                    // don't call if api was used and not key press
                    if (e.originalEvent !== undefined)
                        tp_inst._onTimeChange();
                    tp_inst._onSelectHandler();
                }                    
            });
        return obj;
        // generate whatever controls you want here, just return obj
    },
    options: function (tp_inst, obj, unit, opts, val) {
        if (typeof (opts) == 'string' && val !== undefined)
            return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').text(opts, val);
        return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').text(opts);
        // if val==undefined return the value, else return obj
    },
    value: function (tp_inst, obj, unit, val) {
        if (val !== undefined)
            return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').text('value', val);
        return obj.find('.ui-timepicker-input').text('value');
        // if val==undefined return the value, else return obj
    }
}

$('#testid').datetimepicker(
    {
        controlType: myControl1
    }
);
```

By using this code textbox has created for hour and minute, but change event is not working (i.e; not updating with newly entered value, considering default value 00:00).

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are not using some available plugins for this? http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: I am using same timepicker only . In this for time ticker, we have 2 controltypes select and slider, but i need textboxes instead of those.